# How to only call a function once in a fragment android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

When my app starts I call a function that uses retrofit/gson and calls a rest API, then from there the data gets sent to an adapter and place in a recycler view. the problem I'm having is that when I navigate to another fragment and back again the function is called again but the old data stays in the recycler view, causing there to be multiple copies of the same data sitting in the recycler view when I only want it to call once or at least only have one set of data in the recycler view

I have tried a calling the function from the activity instead of the fragment, placing the function into an onCreate method and mathematical if-else expressions all do not produce the desired effect.

My code:

```
MainFragment.kt

class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private var text1list = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var text2list = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var text3list = mutableListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        view.see_codes.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_listFragment2)
        }

        TestGet()


        return view
    }

    val BASE_URL = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/"

    private fun TestGet() {

            val api = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(SimpleApi::class.java)

            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val response = api.phonehome()

                try {
                    for (Mlist in response.Mlist){
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Result + $Mlist")
                        addToList(Mlist.text1, Mlist.text2, Mlist.text3)
                    }

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        setUpRecyclerView()
                    }
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    println("you messed up the connection some how")
                }
            }
    }


    
    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        main_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        main_recyclerview.adapter = MainAdapter(text1list,text2list,text3list)
    }

    private fun addToList(text1: String, text2: String, text3: String){
        text1list.add(text1)
        text2list.add(text2)
        text3list.add(text3)

    }
}
```

My adapter

```
MainAdapter.kt
class MainAdapter(
        private var text1: List<String>, private var text2: List<String>, private var text3: List<String>)  : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var itemtext1 : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text_view_1)
        var itemtext2 : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text_view_2)
        var itmetext3 : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text_View_3)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.carditem,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return text1.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemtext1.text = text1[position]
        holder.itemtext2.text = text2[position]
        holder.itmetext3.text = text3[position]
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have believe I figured out what Is wrong with my app, but first a big thanks to Mehran B, it was he that laid down the groundwork for this solution.

The problem were the `mutableListOf`'s variables at the top of the code. they were holding on the data from the previous call of the function and just adding to them. So first I tried to solve the problem by clearing the data from all the `mutableListOf`'s. well, I couldn't find out how exactly to do that but if anyone knows how please comment.

so what I eventually did was this

```
    if (!Settings.recViewAlreadyUpdated) {
        TestGet()

        Settings.recViewAlreadyUpdated = true

    }else{
        text1list = mutableListOf()
        text2list = mutableListOf()
        text3list = mutableListOf()
        TestGet()
    }
```

what I did was overite or create a new `mutableListOf`(I'm not exactly sure which) if the function had not been used before. big thanks once again to Mehran B https://stackoverflow.com/users/10695663/mehran-b

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can check and see whether RecyclerView.adapter is null or not. and act accordingly.

If it's not `null`, you have already queried and set the adapter.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    view.see_codes.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_listFragment2)
    }

    if (view.main_recyclerview.adapter == null) {
        TestGet()
    }

    return view
}
```

If the problem is only duplicate data in the RecyclerView then you can check if the adapter is null in the `setUpRecyclerView()` function.

```
private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
    if (main_recyclerview.adapter == null) {  
        main_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        main_recyclerview.adapter = MainAdapter(text1list,text2list,text3list)
    }
}
```

### Edit:

As a last resort, you can make a separate kotlin file named `extensions` or something and have an object in it as below:

```
object Settings{
    var recViewAlreadyUpdated : Boolean = false
}
```

this variable is created when the app runs and lives as long as the app lives so you can use this flag to load your data into your RecyclerView like so:

```
if (!Settings.recViewAlreadyUpdated) {
    TestGet()
    Settings.recViewAlreadyUpdated = true
}
```

Comment: While the concept here seems to be the right idea, It's difficult to tell from the OP's code if this solution will work. The question does not include how `main_recyclerview` is declared or initialized, so we can't know if it will ever be null. We might need to dig a level deeper and check if the recycler view has an adapter.

Comment: sorry my bad. edited the answer. you need to get the recView reference from the view you are loading int the fragment. try it now

Comment: sorry mehran, but the code does not work, it crashes the app. it says :    java.lang.NullPointerException: main_recyclerview must not be null
        at com.notifiyr.fragments.main.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.kt:50)

thank you though

Comment: isn't the recyclerView in the `fragment_main` xml file?

Comment: Check the second part of the answer i just edited. since you are running the function in a coroutine, it shouldn't give you a an NPE.

Comment: it still calls the function over agin but thank you.

Comment: Bro I feel like there is something wrong with the architecture of your app. this shouldn't happen.

Comment: that is entirely conceivable my friend, do you know of a way for a function to be called only once or to check if the function has already been called. but hey its a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Just edited another approach in my answer. if this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: goodish news, it works but has unintended effects, it doesn't load the contents of the recycler view. then I tried putting an else statement that called the setUpRecyclerView() fun. it gave me an NPE and said 
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.

Comment: @MehranB thank you for the help I was able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach here is to only create the `RecyclerView` and it's `Adapter` once. Then you update the data stored by the adapater and call `notifyDataChanged()`.

Comment: it intrigues me. please elaborate, I have used 'notifyDataChanged()' before but I can't quite get it to work here.